# insert_many mongoDB and how to ignore duplicate inserts in a session transaction

Tags: mongodb, transactions, pymongo

I was using PyMongo without any transaction and sessions before and was inserting documents successfully as:

```
try:
    _ = db[collection].insert_many(dataset, ordered=False)
except:
    err = filter(lambda x: x['code'] != 11000, e.details['writeErrors'])
    if len(err) > 0:
        raise
```

The code above was successfully ignoring the errors about duplicate keys, which is what I wanted.

Now, I upgraded to MongoDB 4.0 and tried the new transactions API and tried to do this in a session as:

```
def do_insert(db, dataset, session):
    try:
        _ = db[collection].insert_many(dataset, ordered=False, session=session)
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError as e:
        pass
```

However, the operation also generates an `OperationFailure` error and I get something like:

```
ERROR: test_insert_duplicate_categories (__main__.TestDefaultAnnotations)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xargon/Dropbox/infermatica/code/alchera/altrack/altrack/tests/test_mongodb_default.py", line 152, in test_insert_duplicate_categories
    insert_dataset(db, ds)
  File "/Users/xargon/Dropbox/infermatica/code/alchera/altrack/altrack/data/default.py", line 269, in insert_dataset
    session.commit_transaction()
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 393, in commit_transaction
    self._finish_transaction_with_retry("commitTransaction")
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 457, in _finish_transaction_with_retry
    return self._finish_transaction(command_name)
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 452, in _finish_transaction
    parse_write_concern_error=True)
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 514, in _command
    client=self.__client)
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 579, in command
    unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 150, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/deep/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Transaction 1 has been aborted.
```

The call is as:

```
with db.client.start_session() as session:
    try:
        session.start_transaction()
        do_insert(db, dataset, session)
        session.commit_transaction()
    except Exception as e:
        session.abort_transaction()
        raise
```

How can I ignore this duplicate key error in a transactional setting? The problem is that even though I ignore the duplicate key exception, the transaction now seems to be in an inconsistent state. So when I commit, it throws up that exception.

So, my use case is that I can have users trying to insert duplicates and the database should silently ignore the insert if a record already exists

Comment: Looks like it is not possible at the moment. All errors abort the transaction: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34059 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-11493

Answer (score 2):

> How can I ignore this duplicate key error in a transactional setting?

As you're aware, as of current stable version of MongoDB (v4.0) a `DuplicatedKey` error will abort transactions.

This is because `DuplicatedKey` is only checked after the data write, and the convention is abort the [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) transaction. 
This applies to any index constraints will result in the same issue, e.g. inserting invalid location format into geo index.

> I upgraded to MongoDB 4.0 and tried the new transactions API and tried to do this in a session.

Please note that upgrading to MongoDB 4.0, doesn't mean that you have to also update your code to use [multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/). Only if the use case requires atomicity for updates to multiple documents or consistency between reads to multiple documents.